# Can't switch layout with ctrl+shift with Tweaks

Tags: gnome, keyboard-layout, ibus

I use ibus with two layouts: Dvorak for Latin alphabets and Array for Chinese. I've been switching between the two using ctrl+shift, which I set up using gnome-tweaks, for months without any problem. But recently it stopped working. I don't recall making any changes other than regular updates. Furthermore, every now and then the Dvorak layout would stop working: even though the layout indicator still says Dvorak, the letters that appear when I type are Qwerty.

The default in gnome for layout switching is super+space, and that still works, but gnome's keyboard shortcut interface does not allow me to change it to ctrl+shift.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release?

Comment: @Pilot6 I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.1. I recently further noticed that while the layout indicator doesn't change, ctrl+shift actually switches the layout in a Dvorak-Qwerty-Qwerty cycle, despite me having only set up two layouts.